# php date conversion between different formats

Tags: php, datetime

I've some data which formatted like: 04.09.1953

I want to convert this format to: 1953-09-04

Is there any way or php function to do this?

Comment: Do you want to print your date differently, or to convert an existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get a timestamp and then [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert that timestamp to the format you need:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("04.09.1953");
echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

**EDIT:**
If you're having some "exotic" format as input, you might need to use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to build the timestamp on your own:

```
list($y,$m,$d) = explode(".","04.09.1953");
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y);
echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried strtotime() ? It might work, else you'll need to do manual conversion using substrings or explodes.

http://php.net/strtotime

http://php.net/substring

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

http://www.handyphp.com/index.php/PHP-Resources/Handy-PHP-Functions/reformat_date.html

```
function reformat_date($date, $format){
$output = date($format, strtotime($date));
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in is converting from one "string" format to another you can use a regEx:

$DMY = '04.09.1953';

$YMD = preg_replace('/(\d\d).(\d\d).(\d{4,4})/',  '$3-$2-$1', $DMY);